# IOS Simulator showing wrong coordinates

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, coordinates

I´m using coordinates to get the weather and it works fine. The city name is shown on a UILabel. Everything works good until I run the app on my Iphone and the city name appearing is totally wrong.

I thought that maybe the simulator still decides the location, but when I disconnect my phone and run the app it still shows the wrong city.

Does anyone know of this issue? Is it the simulator that haunts the app when I run it on the phone or do you think it´s code-related?

EDIT:

I use Reactive Cocoa and CLLocationManager

```
- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;

    _client = [[WXClient alloc] init];

    [[[[RACObserve(self, currentLocation)
        ignore:nil]
       // Flatten and subscribe to all 3 signals when currentLocation updates
       flattenMap:^(CLLocation *newLocation) {
           return [RACSignal merge:@[
                                     [self updateCurrentConditions],
                                     [self updateDailyForecast],
                                     [self updateHourlyForecast]
                                     ]];
       }] deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler]
     subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
         [TSMessage showNotificationWithTitle:@"Fel" subtitle:@"Det gick inte att hämta vädret."  
 type:TSMessageNotificationTypeError];
     }];
}
return self;
}

- (void)findCurrentLocation {
self.isFirstUpdate = YES;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
if (self.isFirstUpdate) {
    self.isFirstUpdate = NO;
    return;
}

CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

if (location.horizontalAccuracy > 0) {
    self.currentLocation = location;
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
}

- (RACSignal *)updateCurrentConditions {
return [[self.client fetchCurrentConditionsForLocation:self.currentLocation.coordinate]   
doNext:^(WXCondition *condition) {
    self.currentCondition = condition;
}];
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information before people can help you. Where are you? What is wrong about the city name? Where does the iPhone think it is? What code do you use to get the location of the iPhone? What code do you use to convert the location to a city name?

Right now your question amounts to "I did something and it doesn't work" to which the only answer is "That's because you did it wrong".

Comment: You should also also explain what you mean by "totally wrong". If you're in San Francisco and you're getting Oakland (inaccurate gps) it might be a different problem to you being in Syndey and getting Bejing (co-ordinates inverted?).

Comment: Also you'd do yourself a favour by adding in some debug code to log the location that is accepted before you stopUpdatingLocation and the location that is used to fetchCurrentConditionsForLocation. If they are different then you'll need to track down who changed it. If they are the same then you'll need to see if they are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Stupid mistake. Only updated the labels in viewDidLoad so the city name didn´t change but the coordinates were correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you stop updating the location as soon as the accuracy is greater than 0, but what if the accuracy is 10,000km? You should instead check if the location is valid and then that the accuracy is LESS than some value. The naming of that attribute isn't very good. In this case a lower value for the accuracy is a more accurate location.